# Suppose $C\subseteq A$ is a chain in $A$, then $\cup C\in A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of 3(i):
[image]
I have several questions regarding this proof:

1. $C$ is a subset of $A$, and $A\subseteq (\cup X)^X$. Then why is $\cup C\subseteq X\times \cup X$? Doesn't $X\times \cup X$ represent a function from $X$ to $\cup X$ and $\cup C$ include many function like this?
2. Why do we have $b_1 =b_2$? If $b_1=b_2$, doesn't it mean $f_1(a)=b_1$? And since $(a,b_i)$ are arbitrary, $f_1=f_2$?
3. Why is $F$ partial choice function? What are we suppose to show in order to prove this? $F(x)\in x$ for all $x\in X$? In which part is the proof showed this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(\cup X)^X$ is the set of all functions with domain exactly $X$ and that map into $\cup X$.  Members of $A$ have domain $Y\subseteq X$ which may be a proper subset of $X$.  So it's false to say that $A\subseteq (\cup X)^X$.  If $f$ is a partial choice function then $f\subseteq X\times\cup X$, i.e. $f\in\mathcal{P}(X\times\cup X)$ where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes power-set.  Since $A$ is a collection of partial choice functions, $A\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X\times\cup X)$.  Now, since $C\subseteq A$ then $C\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X\times\cup X)$.  From this follows that $\cup C\subseteq X\times\cup X$ by a lemma that says that if $S, T$ are any sets then $S\subseteq\mathcal{P}(T)\iff\cup S\subseteq T$.
2. $(a,b_1)\in f_1\subseteq f_2$ and $(a,b_2)\in f_2$.  Since $f_2$ is a function and $(a,b_1),(a,b_2)\in f_2$ then $b_1=b_2$.  You can't conclude that $f_1=f_2$ because $f_2$ may have a strictly bigger domain than $f_1$.
3. You have to show that $\operatorname{Domain}(F)\subseteq X$, that $F$ is a function, that $F$ maps into $\cup X$ and that $F(a)\in a$ for all $a\in\operatorname{Domain}(F)$.  We have from above that $F=\cup C\subseteq X\times\cup X$.  This implies that $\operatorname{Domain}(F)\subseteq X$ and that $F$ maps into $\cup X$.  The second part shows that if $(a,b_1),(a,b_2)\in F$ then $b_1=b_2=F(a)\in a$.  This shows that $F$ is a function on its domain and that it chooses an element from its argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I just have one more question, How are $f_i\in C$ and $F$ related?

Comment: @laikaka: $f_1\subseteq f_2\subseteq F$ and $f_2$ is the restriction of $F$ to the domain of $f_2$.